# Failed audit: debatable link only?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Late answers queue.

The review system says that this answer should be deleted, when formally full answer is given:

- Q: "Does it support more then 1...?"
- A: "You can now use up to 3.."

Given link is also healthy: it points to another Stack Overflow psot [how to detect language spoken in google cloud platform machine learning speech api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129195/how-to-detect-language-spoken-in-google-cloud-platform-machine-learning-speech-a?rq=1)

Is it really so obvious case to be used in review audit to check the reviewer's focus?

**"Bad" answer:**
[image]

Comment: But the only thing that "answer" is doing it is pointing to another answer in a different question. You clicked on "Looks OK" on that?

Comment: Yes I've clicked "Looks OK". I do not agree that "only pointing". It formally replies: "up to 3", when question was "does... more then 1?". Formal logic  is preserved.

Comment: The question asks "Is there a way to get Google Cloud Speech API to understand more than 1 language?". And this is only answered by the link but not in the answer itself. The answer should be deleted and the question closed as a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: @BDL , You give us your interpretation not "direct citation". Together proving - this is debatable case.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij: I cited from the image of the question you posted (second to last sentence). I did not  interpretation of the question in any way.

Comment: This is an interpretation. You choose one from two.

Answer (score 12):

Only with the narrowest intepretation of the question you can accept that *"Yes, you can use up to three"* is a valid answer.

Despite the question being awkwardly written, it's pretty clear that the questioner want's more than a "yes/no" answer, but that actually wants to use more than one language with the API.

The answerer of the post your reviewed realized that, and pointed to a post with a answer to the problem at hand.

An answer like that does not *look ok* in my book. In my opinion the audit is perfectly valid, and you chose poorly when clicked on "No action needed".

The fact that the audit wasn't "obvious enough" (according to you), doesn't make it a bad audit. It just means that you need to give reviews a bit more thought and attention.

I think the audit is a pretty obvious one, but if one were uncertain in any way then opening the question to check the other answers to the question would have been advisable (that is something particulary useful in the late answer queue).

There are two options here:

- Continue arguing than the audit was wrong, and get frustrated about it;
- Learn from the experience and review better in the future.

The latter will be much more productive

Comment: You are saying "in my book" - that means agree that this is experience based. When review goal is to check focus not personal experience.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij: This is not a matter of personal experience or anything else. If a answer doesn't fully answer the question without the link (which this one doesn't), then it's link only and should be deleted. In this special case, it is even more obvious because the question itself is a duplicate. A audit is good when it checks if reviewers are reviewing correctly.

Comment: @BDL, again you confirm that this case should not be used in review (because it is a duplicate).

Comment: @Roman, and why would that mean it shouldn't be used as a review audit? It did seem pretty effective in your case.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij: Maybe I don't understand your point. The review seems to be perfectly chosen because it checks if you are paying attention and choose the right option. Either you thought that the answer fully answers the question without the link given (which means you should read the question more carefully and not just the first sentence), or you did think that links only-answers to other SO questions are fine (which they aren't).

Comment: IMHO, reviewer on "late answers" queue should not evaluate such things (as duplication). Only formal factors.

Comment: I don't know what makes you think so. Checking if the answer matches the question is one of your tasks in the Late answer queue. Also checking if the answer is link-only is one of your tasks (and a very formal factory).

Comment: First (match) passed. Second (link only) -  debatable. Third (duplication) - can't be applied.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij, yes duplication *can* be applied, you can open the question in a new tab and manually flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Alberto, the questions is : should reviewer check for it?

Comment: @Roman that the question is a dupe or not is not really relevant (although obvious if you see that the answer you are reviewing is "answering" by pointing to another post). You are reviewing an answer, and if you removed the link what you have left is not something that can be used to answer the question. _"No action needed"_? I do not think so.

Comment: @Roman Again, if I were you I'd try not to fight this, but to use it to learn to review better. All of us failed one or more audits at different points. No big deal. You just learn from it and move on.

Comment: @Roman, if you want to fail Zero (0) audits, you'll have to learn to open the full post to see the context. And learn how to act in that context based on SO rules. Also, link only answers should be at maximum comments if people aren't going to post the solution and only the link.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that answer is clearly link-only, even if it points to another question/answer in Stack Overflow. The text of the answer says *what* can you do but not *how* can you do it (note that the OP also asks if there is a way of to support more that one language).

Maybe padd13bear didn't want to attribute the solution to himself/herself, but in that case the best option (or at least what I do in that cases) is quote the relevant part of the question/blog post/article where you found the solution and then include a link to it for attribution and further reading.

Also, if you found that you have to include the full answer as the quote to answer the question then that question is a duplicate of the linked answer, so padd13bear should have flagged the question as a duplicate instead of trying to answer it.

Comment: I agree about "flagging" as duplicate. The consequence would be that this depatable case would not be used in review audit. And this is what I'm saying.

Comment: I think that the answer was perfect for an audit because it was a link-only question. And the audit worked as intended, because you thought that it was a valid answer, so maybe you are making other incorrect audits without realizing it. Maybe you should search about this topic here in meta to get a clearer picture, there are a lot of discussions about that.

Comment: No that’s an argument that it _should_ be used. Someone failed to do their job properly, they should’ve flagged for duplicate rather than provide a non-answer, so you were tested to see if you’d make the same mistake. Which you did. The system demonstrably works as intended.

Comment: to get SO votes is enough.

Comment: @Clive - if you want to say "from system" then points the rule's article (obligation to check for duplications). othewiese it is only an opinion.

Comment: Sorry but no. Some things are just common sense.

Comment: And you’re not being asked to check for duplicates anyway, I have no idea why you insist on focusing on that. It wasn’t an answer to the question, it was a link to another answer. Anything else can be ignored for the purposes of this discussion.

Comment: @Clive, it seems you do not understand that when you can ignore this, others can't ignore. That was not me who bring this argument on the discussion, I agree to ignore with those who ignore, together should reply to those who use it against my position.

Comment: I have no idea what you’re talking about, sorry

Comment: I'm talking that I agree that the fact of duplication question can be ignored in our (my with you) discussion. But you are not only there.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was joining the existing discussion, not starting a separate one. Both our comments pertain to the wide discussion, not a different one. Anyway you don’t seem willing to listen to what people are telling you, rather trying to argue increasingly vanishing tangential points, so I’m out.